# x86 mov opcode disassembling

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, x86-64, disassembly

I have built in IDE x86 debbuger which disassemble this:

First case:

```
65 48 8B 05 30 00 00 00
mov rax,gs:[rel $00000030]
```

Second case:

```
65 48 8B 04 25 30 00 00 00
mov rax,gs:[+$0030]
```

What is the difference?

I suspect that something is wrong with disassembling but can't translate upper opcodes.

What I know is:

- `65` is `gs` prefix
- `48` is `REX.W` prefix
- `8B` is `mov` ...
- ...???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first one is RIP relative, while the second one is and absolute address.

For a translation of the opcodes, see http://www.sandpile.org .
As Polynomial noted, http://ref.x86asm.net is even better but does currently not have support for AVX or XOP.

- `8B` - opcode - is given as `mov Gv, Ev`, where Gv indicates a register target, where Ev is a r/m destination.
- `05` - mod r/m - indicate `rax` as target, with `rip` relative as effective address
- `30 00 00 00` the offset to `rip`

The second one:

- `8B` - opcode - is given as `mov Gv, Ev`, where Gv indicates a register target, where Ev is a r/m destination.
- `04` - mod r/m - indicate `rax` as target, with `sib` as effective address
- `25` - sib - address is in format [basereg + indexreg*stride + offset], in this case both base and index are 0.
- `30 00 00 00` the offset.

Comment: Thank you - this was the site I was looking for! I swear it was somewhere in my bookmarks, but I must have accidently deleted it.

Comment: So, if I understand than in first case the address is relative (rip + 0x30) and in the second case the address is absolute.

Comment: Re: "both base and index are 0": why? if sib is `25`, then base is `101` and index is `100`. Do I miss something?

Comment: UPD. I've found answers in comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48992007/1778275).