# x86 - what's wrong with SIB byte 00 100 101 combination in 32 bits?

Tags: encoding, x86, instructions

For my assembler, I want to encode the operation `mov eax, [addr]`. In 64 bits this would only possible using a SIB byte, as the mod r/m combination 00 101 was changed to indicate rip-relative addressing. The problem I find is that, in 32 bits, encoding this instruction using a SIB byte doesn't work. For example I have:

```
  8B           84           25     1C FE 43 00  
(mov) (10 000 100) (00 100 101)     (address)
```

but disassemblers don't seem to accept it, I get:

```
mov eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+eiz*1+0x43fe1c]  (defuse.ca)
mov eax, ss:off_43FE1C[ebp]             (ida)
```

and when the instruction is executed it generates an exception. I know that there is the shorter encoding in 32 bits, but don't understand what's wrong with the longer one.

Comment: According to [this diagram](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/X77_0100_sib_byte_layout.htm), an index of `100` as shown in your SIB `00 100 101` is illegal. What instruction are you actually trying to create?

Comment: I don't know the source of the info they show there, but actually using 100 for index is the standard way of denoting that there is no index register. The Intel manual for that index says "none", and normally (except in this problematic combintation of modrm/sib) it works ok.

Comment: Yes, I did notice the "none" in some documents, so I wondered about the discrepancy. So if I read the Intel correctly, the instruction should be, validly, `mov eax, [ebp + disp32]`, or literally, in your example, `mov eax, [ebp + 0x43FE1C]`, does that sound right?

Comment: Yes, except that it isn't :) This happens because for the base field, 101, which would normally mean ebp, with mod = 00 means no base field. The encoding format is really complex.

Comment: Ohhh! now you made me see that I was mistakenly putting the mod bits in 10 instead of 00. Correcting that it just works! Thanks!!!

Comment: So was the fault a segfault (memory protection), rather than invalid instruction?  You could have just put `mov eax, [0x43fe1c]` into an assembler to find out how to encode it.  (In NASM, the default is absolute addressing, or use `mov eax, [abs 0x43fe1c]` if you had used `default rel` earlier in the file.